# How to use deleteAll in parse.com

Tags: ios, parse-platform

Can someone give me an example of how to use the deleteAll method in Parse.com as referenced [here](https://www.parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFObject.html#//api/name/deleteAll%3a)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is pretty basic Objective-C syntax. I've never used parse, but seeing as though this is a class method of PFObject with a BOOL return value, you can call this function like this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfObjectsToDelete = ...
[PFObject deleteAll:arrayOfObjectsToDelete];
```

Now mind you, this is how you could use it if you don't care about its return value, but if you're interested in wether or not the deletion was successful, you would use it like this:

```
NSArray *arrayOfObjectsToDelete = ...
if ([PFObject deleteAll:arrayOfObjectsToDelete]) {
    //success
}else{
    //failed
}
```

Comment: That's exactly what I tried, but I get the error "No known class method for selector 'deleteAll:"

Comment: @Phil Are you sure everything is being imported correctly? I don't see any reason why this shouldn't work.

Comment: Yeah I think so, everything else to do with using the PFObject seems to work fine.

Comment: Did you update your Parse SDK after this feature was announced?

Comment: In the end I just went through them all and deleted them individually, takes a few seconds, but get's the job done. To answer your question, not sure but i'll look into that.